# Cannot read property of null even though the EJS template is working fine

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Having a problem with my express app, trying to set up get route for a users profile page. The user information is displaying in the EJS file but I am still getting the error:

```html
 1| 
    2| 
 >> 3| <p><%= user.posts %></p>
    4| 
    5| 
    6| 

Cannot read property 'posts' of null
```

My user get route:

```js
router.get("/:username", (req, res)=>{
    // Find user from request
    
    var user = req.params.username;
    console.log(user);
    User.findOne({username: user}).populate("posts").exec((err, foundUser)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //render user profile template
            res.render("user/show", {user:foundUser});
        }
    });
});
```

When I console.log(req.params.username) I get two usernames, the one i'm looking for and "favicon.ico". I'm thinking thats why the null error is there, the page displays the right username first but then the second causes an error. Not sure what to do about it though.

If you need me to send more code then let me know, this is my first post on here!!

Comment: cant you just use (user && user.posts) || ""

Comment: Do you mean in my EJS file?

Comment: yes. I have not used ejs as such, but i think its using js expressions, so it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the browser will send a request for `/favicon.ico` to display the icon between tabs. In order to prevent that you can include a separate route to handle the request.

```js
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));
```

Think this would take care of your `null` error.